# Why clang AST shows two CXXRecordDecl for a single class?

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree, libtooling

I'm trying to build tools with libtooling.
when using clang to dump AST, i found that two CXXRecordDecl were reported for class Foo.
It seems that the outer CXXRecordDecl has a CXXRecordDecl child which says it's implicit class Foo.
Why is that?

[image: Definition]

[image: AST Dump]

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a class declaration.

In your example, you can notice that these two *CXXRecordDecl*'s have different locations and the nested one corresponds to *Foo*'s forward declaration. Without a forward declaration, definition will be pointing at itself.

Answer (score 0):

At lease it's useful to know how to match one over the other:

```
// test.cpp
class Foo {};
int main() { return 0; }
```

using ast matcher

```
clang-query> m cxxRecordDecl(hasName("Foo"))
Match #1:
test.cpp:2:1: note: "root" binds here
class Foo {
^~~~~~~~~~~
Match #2:
test.cpp:2:1: note: "root" binds here
class Foo {
^~~~~~~~~
2 matches.

clang-query> m cxxRecordDecl(hasName("Foo"),unless(isImplicit()))
Match #1:
test.cpp:2:1: note: "root" binds here
class Foo {
^~~~~~~~~~~
1 match.
```

It's not a forward declaration, probably a compiled defined implicit constructor.